# Having multiple input file in *ngfor with same variable name

Tags: angular, input

I'm creating a table that for each line will permit to upload a different file. 
This upload will be done as soon as the file is put inside the input. For now I'm able to achieve this with this code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let attachment of attachments">
        <td class="p-0"><input type="text" [value]="attachment.title"/></td>
        <td>{{attachment.filename}}
          <button (click)="attachmentInput.click()" *ngIf="!attachment.filename">
          </button>
          <input type="file" accept="application/pdf" (click)="attachmentInput.value = null"
                 (change)="editAttachment(attachmentInput.files, attachment.id)" hidden #attachmentInput>
        </td>
</tr>
```

This seems to works, but I'm giving for all the input tags the same variable name `attachmentInput`, I thought that this could lead to a problem since when I click the button, it could not know which input element to refer since they all have the same name, but seems like it's not the case.

Is this an approach that could cause some problems? Is there any alternative?

Comment: Put the upload logic inside a component that receives the `attachment` as input

Comment: I would recommend to use @ViewChildren on #attachmentInput. This will give you a list of all the elements and using the array index you can perform any action. This will give you more control of the input.

Comment: @EliasSoares sorry I'm having problems to visualize your solution

Comment: @AkashAgrawal where do I set the array index? on #attachmentInput + index? And how to I call the click on the input file?

Comment: Create a stackblitz of your code. I'll update it.